# SQL Server: permissions to read database diagrams

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, database-permissions

Could you please advise, what are permissions required to give user access to read Database diagrams in SQL Server 2005?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [See workaround here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43967/1186).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> - Although any user with access to a database can create a diagram, once the diagram has been created, the only users who can see it are the diagram's creator and any member of the db_owner role.
> - Ownership of diagrams can only be transferred to members of the db_owner role. This is only possible if the previous owner of the diagram has been removed from the database.
> - If the owner of a diagram has been removed from the database, the diagram will remain in the database until a member of the db_owner role attempts to open it. At that point the db_owner member can choose to take over ownership of the diagram.

So, db_owner/dbo is best

Answer (score 8):

Try with this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::AdventureWorks TO sa;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would help please?

Comment: Question was what permission are needed for user to create diagram, and not which user has permissions to create diagram. Logically, `sa` user is `sysadmin` and has full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de6cb842-ecac-4c6e-b5b7-85ae62edbc0e/cant-create-database-diagrams?forum=sqlsecurity):

> ... you can grant execute premission on sp_creatediagram stored
>   procedure to someone who needs to create the diagram; you can grant
>   execute alter, rename or drop permisson as well. However, please note
>   that you still need related premission on tables, schemas otherwise
>   you may not be able to save the diagram. For instance, if you create a
>   new table in the diagram, you need CREATE TABLE permission on
>   corresponding Schema

less than db_owner/dbo